# How Do I Comibine These If Statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I would like to combine these if statements.

I currently have `=IF(J2<=K2,"Y","N")`

But first:

I would like for this IF statement to return "N" if J2 is = I2.
If J2 is not = to I2 I would then like for it to then look at the formula `IF(J2<=K2,"Y","N")` and return "Y" or "N"

Thus the logic for the test would be:

- J2 == I2 → `"N"`
- J2 <> I2 → `IF(J2<=K2,"Y","N")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting the `IF` functions:

```
=IF(J2=I2 ; "N"; IF(J2<=K2; "Y"; "N"))
```

Comment: What is the proper way to write the formula.  I currently have what you wrote above as =IF(J7=I7,"N",IF((J7<=K7,"Y","N")  But its giving me an error

Comment: You're missing the last ')' and you have two '(' instead of just one in the middle

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested IF statements for this.

```
=IF(J2=I2, "N", IF(J2<=K2,"Y","N"))
```

The first (outer) IF checks to see if J2 is equal to I2 and returns "N" if they are equal.  If not, it returns the result of the nested IF statement.